# GetHashCode method for Generic HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, generics, hash

I'm trying to write a Generic IEqualityComparer for an HashSet, such that two set are equals if and only if their elements match.

So, Equals will look like:

```
    public bool Equals(HashSet<T> A, HashSet<T> B)
    {
        return (A.All(x => B.Contains(x)) && B.All(x => A.Contains(x)));
    }
```

I am having much more trouble finding a good GetHashCode method. I am aware that

```
    public int GetHashCode(HashSet<int> obj)
    {
        return 1;
    }
```

is always an option, but I'd like to have something better than that. Has anybody an idea on how i could do that? Is using ToString on each element, order and join them, and get the hashcode for the resulting string a bad idea?

Comment: For `Equals`, it is simpler to use `return A.SetEquals(B);`.

Comment: You could check what the IEqualityComparer  does that is returned by the [HashSet<T>.CreateSetComparer Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475.aspx).

Comment: @dtb Great comment (could almost be an answer in itself).

Answer (score 0):

The [`IEqualityComparer<T> Interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) abstract the set of operations required here:

- `Equals`
- `GetHashode`

You can get the *default comparer* like all .NET classes do: using the [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx)

However, it is my understanding that `HashSet<>` has the policy to use the `Comparer` associated with the object that you invoke an operation on, even if it takes another HashSet as an argument.